# How to Update ExpandableList Items Outside of ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android

I've a ExpandableListAdapter in which I'm using populating child with holder like this

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    ChildElement e= new ChildElement();
    e.childPosition = childPosition;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item, null);


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_icon);
        holder.Save_check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        ////holder.Save_check.setTag(childPosition);

        holder.Remarks = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remarks);
        holder.Qty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);

        holder.Date = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        ////holder.Date.setTag(childPosition);
        holder.Time = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        ////holder.Time.setTag(childPosition);
        holder.itemname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_icon);

        holder.Date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int getDPPostion = (Integer) holder.Date.getTag();
                String DP = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString();
                long SP = getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
                GP = groupPosition; CP = childPosition;
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                globalPosition = holder.ref;
            }
        });

        ////convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.itemname.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString().toLowerCase());

    return convertView;

}
```

and out side the adapter i've Date Listner like this

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;
        ///final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        //final ViewHolder holder;
        //int getPostion = (Integer) view.getTag();
        String date = (month + 1)+"/"+year;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.Date.setText(date);
   };
```

and a dialog

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(MenuScreen.this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                    day);
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            // set time picker as current time
            return new TimePickerDialog(MenuScreen.this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                    false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

but it gives null pointer exception.

Comment: post the log showing the exception, it will help determine the cause

Comment: it says log is too long how to post that

Comment: just add the bit which says where the problem is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Printer.printString(Printer.java:13)
    at Printer.print(Printer.java:9)
    at Printer.main(Printer.java:19)` for example, it basically tells you the class and line where the problem occurs.

Comment: at sg.MenuScreen$4.onDateSet(MenuScreen.java:587)
                                                                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:116)

Comment: at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:169)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: i m able to load Date dialog on "Date Edit Text" of Child view but it crashes when date is selected and assigned to holder.Date.setText(date);

Comment: check that holder is not null and the date is not null

Comment: i commented the Line holder = new ViewHolder(); but now its assigning value to Date Edit Text of last child Item instead of selected child Item Edit Text

Comment: i commented it in datePickerListener

Comment: how to give reference of Selected Edit text of Child view Out of ExpandableListAdapter in datePickerListener